# ms-access: Added field in query not accessible in further queries

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wrote a query that selects from 32 different tables and unions the results all into a single datasheet. Basically, each year's worth of data is split into 4 tables and then I have 8 years worth of data. So when I select all these, I want to keep an identifier in the row as to which table it was pulled from.

So my select statement looks a lot like this (column and table names omitted due to sensitivity):

`SELECT i.Col1, i.Col2, i.Col3, "2007" as FiscalYear
FROM table1 i
UNION ALL
SELECT i.Col1, i.Col2, i.Col3, "2008" as FiscalYear
FROM table2 i`

So now with these results I need to do some calculations, but the fiscalyear field isn't selectable in further queries. Could anyone explain to me the background operations that are causing the fiscalyear to not be written? Is it just inherent to the query process or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "in further queries"?  If you save what you have as *qryBigUnion*, then use *qryBigUnion* as the data source for a new query, are you saying its *FiscalYear* field is not available?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I can't query that field and when i tried to export it to a different database it didn't come along either

Comment: Can you share a copy of that db?  I don't understand what's going on and am curious whether I can figure it out.

Comment: No, sorry, it's very sensitive :/